# How to get header information of Controll Area Network protocols

Tags: header, can-bus

I'm trying to get header information of CAN frames. All method I found to get CAN frame show only Msg ID and 8 bytes of payload(ex. candump of can tools).
Is there anyone who knows how to get CAN header bits from CAN frames?

I've tried to find some options of candump and some python example code such as;

import cantools
import can
can_bus = can.interface.Bus('slcan0', bustype='socketcan')
data = can_bus.recv()
print(data)
data_data = data.data
data_id = data.arbitration_id #can프로토콜 ID

However, I was not able to find a way to get header bits of CAN frames.

Comment: This is CAN controller/tool chain-specific and you don't mention which one you use, so the question cannot be answered.